# No errors on backend, but Ajax function is failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have an Ajax Call and a Controller with some methods and there is something weird.

The Ajax call can reach the Controller Method. The method is returning the value perfectly, no errors, nothing. However, in the AJAX the return is coming with error (not on success of Ajax).

Moreover, If I inspect the return I can see the correct values on responseJson, but the status is 404 and statusText is "error" ({"readyState":4,"status":404,"statusText":"error"})

Anyone have an idea what is going on? There is no error in backend, however error in Ajax.

**Controller Method**

```
public JsonResult SceneListUpdated(string sceneId)
        {
            SceneListModel model = new SceneListModel();
            var licenseValidationState = KeygenLicenseState.CheckLicense();
            if (licenseValidationState == 0)
            {
                SceneListService sceneService = new SceneListService();
                model = sceneService.GetSceneListUpdated(sceneId);
                return Json(new { Success = true, data = model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
            }
            return Json(new { Success = false, data = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**Ajax Function**

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/api/test/SceneList/SceneListUpdated?sceneId=" + sceneIdAux,  //Method in controller
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (e) {
            
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Why an extra closing } in the success callback?

Comment: My bad, just happened in Copy&Paste.

Comment: in network tab your request also marked as 404?

Comment: @demo yes, 404 . Its weird because if I put the url in the browser, I can see the results

Comment: 404 but response is correct?

Answer (score 1):

try to fix the ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/api/test/SceneList/SceneListUpdated/"+ sceneIdAux,  //Method in controller
        type: "GET",
         success: function (e) {
          
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    });
```

and maybe you can try one of these routing since you have 404

```
[Route("{sceneId}")]
[Route("~/api/SceneList/SceneListUpdated/{sceneId}")]
public JsonResult SceneListUpdated(string sceneId)
```

Comment: This is not the problem, I just copied and removed some ifs to post here. Forgot to remove one }

Comment: @FernandoFeks Can you show the controller too?